# How to block a conversation on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I would like to block a conversation I'm into on Facebook so none can add me back in there. I have some friends in the conversation so they add me back when I leave but I don't want them to do that. They do it for fun so they just add me back all the time. I don't want to delete them or block them obviously. That being said, can I block only the conversation and keep myself out of it so none can add me back in?

Comment: Uhm you can try to "Turn off Chat" so that would only reduce their chances of talking to you because you're shown as "Offline".

Answer (score 1):

You can allow to add you back then mute the conversation.

[image: Mute them]

Comment: Yup. I know that. I would prefer it though if I wasn't in the group at all.

Comment: You can make the chat offline for the selected friends so you would be available as offline for friends.You can do it by going to advanced settings in the chat option and then turn off the chat for selected friends.                                                                    If you are in group,then there would be icon called manage groups in the left side.It would open all the groups and then select the wheel con near the group and then chose option leave the group while checking the option dont allow to add backup.This would help you so they cant be able to add it.

Answer (score -2):

I keep gettin these sexual text messages  and they will not stop. When I write Stop or OPTOUT.this one today is from 1-484-729-7032